# 100 Years of GCHQ - A quick afternoon puzzle!

Tags: cipher, no-computers

I'm off to the Science Museum London tomorrow, to the Exhibition celebrating 100 years of GCHQ. As such, they sent me a little reminder email this afternoon.

On the bottom of the email was the following code:

> Bv qthv utj vzptu utjs wcfcn - fvza jf e nbvvn co utj avmsuhnva nqcf mtav!

I thought I would share with you lovely people!

Happy deciphering.

Note: I have no affiliation to the Science museum

Wanted to add a hint for anyone who wants to try and solve without looking below:

> The word `nbvvn` is a hyperlink to the science museum twitter page

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a:

> Cryptogram

It says:

> We hope you enjoy your visit - send us a tweet if you decrypted this code

I solved it by hand in Excel but you can use sites like:

> [quipqiup.com](https://quipqiup.com/)

Comment: Well done, I only just noticed one of the tags so I had to delete my answer. But I took votes I don't deserve. Apologies, to everybody :(